# SQL Server CE Toolbox Performance

Tags: sql-server-ce

When I run a DB query from my application using the SQL Server CE 4.0 DLLs, it takes 5 times longer to return the results than if I run the same query on the same database using the SQL Server CE toolbox plugin to VS2010.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

The query is something like:

SELECT * FROM  WHERE column1 > '' AND column2 < '' AND column3 IN (14)

The database file is quite large at ~600 MB and the table that the query is run against has more than 3 million rows in it.

All 3 of the columns used in the query above are indexed.

The query returns about 5000 rows.

Here are some query performance numbers:

- my code: 1 second
- SQL Server CE toolbox: 0.188 seconds

In my C++ code, I am using ATL/OLEDB to access the database:

```
CCommand<CDynamicParameterAccessorEx> cmd;
    HRESULT hr = videosCmd.Create(dbsession,
        querystmt.c_str());

void* pDummy;

// Bind the parameters.
hr = cmd.BindParameters (/* can't show args here because of SO weirdness */); 


// set the second parameter- start time
DBTIMESTAMP dbStart;
tzLocalTimeToUTC(startLocal, &start_utc);
ConvertTime(start_utc, &dbStart);
videosCmd.SetParam(1, &dbStart);

// set the first parameter- end time
DBTIMESTAMP dbEnd;
tzLocalTimeToUTC(endLocal, &end_utc);
ConvertTime(end_utc, &dbEnd);
videosCmd.SetParam(2, &dbEnd);

hr = cmd.Open();

hr = cmd.MoveFirst();
```

Comment: I think the Toolbox operates on an already open DbConnection, do you do the same in C++ ?

Comment: Yep.  I sort figured out what is going on here.  "Sort of" because there is some performance issue with using the ATL/OLEDB MoveNext method on the CCommand class which is causing the final invocation of that method to take a very long time to execute.  I have posted another question on this but have not received a response as yet.  It seems to be related to the indexes that I have defined for that table (yes, it makes no sense).